# MacOS - Activate a window given its Window ID

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

Is it possible to [activate (bring to the fore)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419208-makekeyandorderfront?language=objc) a window based on the values returned from [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo)? (i.e Using the [window ID (`kCGWindowNumber`) or something else](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/required_window_list_keys).)

Edit:

I should specify that my app (which would run with accessibility permissions) needs to be able to do this for windows of other apps.

Since posting the question I've discovered `AXUIElementPerformAction`. Am I going in the right direction with this?

Or is running AppleScript bridge within my code the best approach?

Comment: of your own app or of any app running?

Comment: For other apps. see edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach to a process by pid and get its windows. Then use `kAXRaiseAction` to bring them to front, like this:

```
AXUIElementRef element = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid);
if (element) {
  CFArrayRef array;
  AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues(element, kAXWindowsAttribute, 0, 99999, &array);

  if (array == nullptr)
    return;

  NSArray *windows = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(array);
  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < windows.count; ++i) {
    AXUIElementRef ref = (__bridge AXUIElementRef)(windows[i]);
    AXError error = AXUIElementPerformAction(ref, kAXRaiseAction);
    // handle error
  }
}

CFRelease(element);
```

No need to release `array` or `windows`. Children in arrays are handled automatically and the array is bridged to an NSArray which is released by ARC.

Comment: I wanted to specifically use the Window ID to identify the window. Since posting the question I've discovered there is no direct way to do this. What can be done though is match the windows (returned by CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo() vs the ones returned by AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues()) based on their title, position and size. In (the rare case of) not being able to find a unique match thus, one could use the AX api to change the window size by 1 pixel or so, and thereby find the exact one that matches the CGWindow of interest.

Comment: But yes, AXRaise is the thing to do afterwards. Followed by NSRunningApplication.activate()

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. +1

Comment: I got it! You have a typo! The sixth from last line should be 
`AXError error = AXUIElementPerformAction(ref, kAXRaiseAction);`

Answer (score 1):

My answer's a little overcomplicated compared to what was already shared by Mike Lischke, but I've already posted it on a different SO question and I think it is a tiny bit closer to what you need:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <libproc.h>
#import <string.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>

bool activate_window_of_id(unsigned long wid) {
  bool success = false;
  const CGWindowLevel kScreensaverWindowLevel = CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey);
  CFArrayRef windowArray = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);
  CFIndex windowCount = 0;
  if ((windowCount = CFArrayGetCount(windowArray))) {
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < windowCount; i++) {
      NSDictionary *windowInfoDictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)((CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowArray, i));
      NSNumber *ownerPID = (NSNumber *)(windowInfoDictionary[(id)kCGWindowOwnerPID]);
      NSNumber *level = (NSNumber *)(windowInfoDictionary[(id)kCGWindowLayer]);
      if (level.integerValue < kScreensaverWindowLevel) {
        NSNumber *windowID = windowInfoDictionary[(id)kCGWindowNumber];
        if (wid == windowID.integerValue) {
          CFIndex appCount = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] count];
          for (CFIndex j = 0; j < appCount; j++) {
            if (ownerPID.integerValue == [[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] objectAtIndex:j] processIdentifier]) {
              NSRunningApplication *appWithPID = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] objectAtIndex:j];
              [appWithPID activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateAllWindows | NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
              char buf[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];
              proc_pidpath(ownerPID.integerValue, buf, sizeof(buf));
              NSString *buffer = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
              unsigned long location = [buffer rangeOfString:@".app/Contents/MacOS/" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;
              NSString *path = (location != NSNotFound) ? [buffer substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, location)] : buffer;
              NSString *app = [@" of application \\\"" stringByAppendingString:[path lastPathComponent]];
              NSString *index = [@"set index of window id " stringByAppendingString:[windowID stringValue]];
              NSString *execScript = [[index stringByAppendingString:app] stringByAppendingString:@"\\\" to 1"];
              char *pointer = NULL;
              size_t buffer_size = 0;
              NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
              FILE *file = popen([[[@"osascript -e \"" stringByAppendingString:execScript] stringByAppendingString:@"\" 2>&1"] UTF8String], "r");
              while (getline(&pointer, &buffer_size, file) != -1)
                [array addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:pointer]];
              char *error = (char *)[[array componentsJoinedByString:@""] UTF8String];
              if (strlen(error) > 0 && error[strlen(error) - 1] == '\n')
                error[strlen(error) - 1] = '\0';
              if ([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:error] isEqualToString:@""])
                success = true;
              [array release];
              free(pointer);
              pclose(file);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  CFRelease(windowArray);
  return success;
}
```

The code it is based on does not work as advertised for its original purpose. Although, it did help me a lot to get working all the stuff I needed to answer this question. [The code my answer is based on can be found here.](https://gist.github.com/matthewreagan/2f3a30b8b229e9e2aa7c)

Comment: Anything you can do with AppleScript you can also do with the `ScriptingBridge` api. (They are both just sending AppleEvents under the hood) It's much easier and faster to use the `ScriptingBridge` api from code compared to embedding raw AppleScript strings in you code! You can even autogenerate a `.h` file containing all the scriptable functionality of an app with a command like this `sdef /Applications/Safari.app/ | sdp -f h -o <Destination Path> --hidden --basename Safari`. To see all the scriptable apps on your system, you can go to `Script Editor > File > Open Dictionary...`